# org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: An exception occurred in the change event producer. This connector will be stopped

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, database-administration, database-replication, debezium

Using postgres source connector in kafka. It works properly for some time and suddently stops with above error. Please assist if someone knows this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This happens if the database is not available and the only way to fix it to restart the connector. I would advise you to check the database logs and see if database is going down or refusing connection to Kafka Connect

Comment: Thanks sandy. I think it is failed due to master slave architecture of my database. whenever master fails, slave comes up and kafka connector fails. Now i have set dag which checks connector status every minute and rePOST it if this error occures. 

It will be really great if you can tell me, can i use replication slot on slave server also?

Comment: At the time of this writing no, you can't use logical replication slots for slave servers: https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.8/connectors/postgresql.html#supported-postgresql-topologies